# accessing elements of a dictionary inside of a format tag: why are keys unquoted?

Tags: python

Given a dictionary

```
dict = {"key":"value"}
```

If elements of a dictionary are accessed like this:

```
dict["key"]
```

How come the following returns an error?

```
"{dict['key']}".format(dict=dict)
```

This seems to be the correct way:

```
"{dict[key]}".format(dict=dict)
```

Quoting elements of a dictionary inside a format string tag seems like it would be more consistent. Is there a reason why format is implemented so it expects unquoted keys?

Also, **where should I expect to find documentation on this behavior**? `str.format?` is only two sentences long. Are there extended helps file somewhere else or a language definition I would expect to find this in? I'm relatively new to Python.

Comment: Python str.format documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method

Comment: @HenryTjhia Maybe I'm missing something but using dictionaries for string formatting isn't even described on that page. Even if it were, is it common in Python for function behavior to only be documented under the tutorial?

Comment: Maybe this could PEP could explain much more: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#simple-and-compound-field-names

Answer (score 1):

You can find the docs here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

and here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec

> The grammar for a replacement field is as follows:

```
replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
arg_name          ::=  [identifier | digit+]
attribute_name    ::=  identifier
element_index     ::=  digit+ | index_string
index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
conversion        ::=  "r" | "s" | "a"
format_spec       ::=  <described in the next section>
```

The fact that the keys are not quote-delimited puts some (documented) limitations on using specific keys in the format string, e.g. given the following dictionary:

```
d = {1: 1, "1":"one", "]":"closing bracket"}
```

This works:

```
print("{d[1]}".format(d=d)) # Output: 1
```

But you cannot access the keys `"1"` or `]`.

From the docs:

> Because arg_name is not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings '10' or ':-]') within a format string.